# I'm trying to sort through my table column by clicking the header without loading the page.

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

What I'm trying to do is when a user clicks on the headers next to sort link, I want it to load without refreshing the whole page. How would I add this onto my code?

**helpers**

```
module ListsHelper
  def sort_link(column, title = nil)
   title ||= column.titleize
   direction = column == sort_column && sort_direction == "asc" ? "desc" : "asc"
   icon = sort_direction == "asc" ? "fas fa-chevron-up" : "fas fa-chevron-down"
   icon = column == sort_column ? icon : ""
   link_to "#{title} <i class='#{icon}'></i>".html_safe, params.merge(:sort => column, direction: direction)
 end
end
```

**views**

```
<div class="demo">
  <br>
  <table class="table is-responsive is-fullwidth">
    <h1>Click header to sort</h1>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th><%= sort_link 'Name'%></th>
        <th><%= sort_link 'Date' %></th>
        <th><%= sort_link 'Number' %></th>
        <th><%= sort_link 'Description' %></th>
        <th colspan="3"></th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <% @lists.each do |list| %>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td><%= list.name %></td>
        <td><%= list.date %></td>
        <td><%= list.number %></td>
        <td><%= list.description %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Show', list %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_list_path(list) %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', list, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
      </tr>

    </tbody>
    <% end %>
  </table>

</div>
```

Comment: Do you want to sort what is currently in the table, or fetch from the database again?

Comment: Sort whats currently in the table

Answer (score 0):

I finally fixed the problem.

The problem was that I had remote: true inside

```
link_to "#{title} <i class='#{icon}'></i>".html_safe, params.merge(:sort => column, direction: direction, remote: true)
```

instead

```
link_to "#{title} <i class='#{icon}'></i>".html_safe, params.merge(:sort => column, direction: direction), remote: true
```